# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' : Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am working on a project in django with pycharm. 
I have this view in the views.py :

```
def all_songs(request, filter_by):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/login.html')
    else:
        try:
            song_ids = []
            for album in Album.objects.all():
                for song in album.song_set.all():
                    song_ids.append(song.pk)
            users_songs = Song.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)
            for album in GenericAlbum.objects.all():
                for song in album.genericsong_set.all():
                    song_ids.append(song.pk)
            generic_songs = GenericSong.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)
        except Album.DoesNotExist:
            users_songs = []
        except GenericAlbum.DoesNotExist:
            generic_songs = []
        return render(request, 'music/songs.html', {
            'song_list_all': users_songs,
            'generic_song_list': generic_songs,
            'filter_by': filter_by,
        })
```

Everything is working fine when I click on the page that run this method, but I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Eminem_-_Mockingbird.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 212992
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Eminem_-_Mockingbird.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59866)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Scorpions_-_Wind_Of_Change.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 1638400
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/The_Cranberries_-_Zombie.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 1597440
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Bon_Jovi_-_Always.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 1449984
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Bon_Jovi_-_Hey_God_Long_Version.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 1318912
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Scorpions_-_Wind_Of_Change.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59868)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/The_Cranberries_-_Zombie.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59869)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Bon_Jovi_-_Hey_God_Long_Version.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/Bon_Jovi_-_Always.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59871)
----------------------------------------
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/eminem__lose_yourself_lyrics.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 794624
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59870)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
[12/Oct/2017 14:57:50] "GET /media/eminem__lose_yourself_lyrics.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59867)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

I am runing django 1.11 with python 3.6.

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 does not support Python 3.6. Django 1.9 is end of life and does not receive security updates, you should really upgrade to the 1.11 LTS version.

Comment: where does `request_user` comes from?

Comment: it comes from the user (user table that django provide)

Comment: I changed django to 1.11, still same problem, so it has nothing to do with the django version I guess

Comment: The problem is not with the view, but that you are running this on the built-in development server, and you are requesting a very large file which is taking too long to serve - and thus the connection gets dropped and this is the cause of your exception.

Answer (score 3):

There is some condition, where your method is returning `None`, which is why you are getting an error from the `wsgi` stack.

You need to always make sure you are returning something from the view methods. You also don't need a `try` since none of your calls will raise the exceptions you are trying to catch.

Further simplified with the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) and your method is now more manageable:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
def all_songs(request, filter_by=None):

    song_ids = []

    for album in Album.objects.all():
      for song in album.song_set.all():
        song_ids.append(song.pk)

    users_songs = Song.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)

    for album in GenericAlbum.objects.all():
      for song in album.genericsong_set.all():
        song_ids.append(song.pk)

    generic_songs = GenericSong.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)

    return render(request, 'music/songs.html', {
            'song_list_all': users_songs,
            'generic_song_list': generic_songs,
            'filter_by': filter_by,
    })
```

Comment: I did what you said, I changed my view to what you did write, and nothing changed, still same problem

Comment: Update the question with the complete error message, the entire traceback.

Comment: Here's the updates, I also did an upgrade to my django from 1.9.4 ==> 1.11

Answer (score 1):

I figured the issue is with Database. Mostly SQLite.
When you make any changes with DB and you forget to commit or revert it, the Database gets into the locked mode, that is the time you encounter this issue. Go to your Database and revert or commit the change to unlock it and everything will be back to normal.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/